# import content from html file into div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import content into a div using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myDiv').load('https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/057957154/needtoknow.html');
});
```

It's not working. Can anyone help please? [JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/wht4ejvz/). End result should have the text "test box 1"

Comment: Tada! now it is working!! https://jsfiddle.net/wht4ejvz/1/

Comment: What @RajaprabhuAravindasamy meant to say is ... you need jQuery library loaded to do this

Comment: aargh dummy me. Thank you, all.

Comment: What if the content of a snippet needs to be loaded using the code as in my question, how would I go about that? The access to the snippet elsewhere in the site is: {% include 'snippets/beginnerscoursetourwithhotel.rain'%}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check you console you will find this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

You need to import Jquery Library to project
working on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wht4ejvz/)

or:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv').load('https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/057957154/needtoknow.html');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, John. Got it.

Comment: What if the content of a snippet needs to be loaded using the code as in my question, how would I go about that? The access to the snippet elsewhere in the site is: {% include 'snippets/beginnerscoursetourwithhotel.rain'%}